# Remove the "Edit" option on ReadTheDocs

Tags: read-the-docs

I am looking to remove the "Edit on Github" option on Readthedocs on this website: https://sparkles-wiki.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ but I can't. I did find some articles on github but it looks like it is outdated.

I tried this: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/2386#issuecomment-217861381

but it didn't work, as I was stuck there: https://img001.prntscr.com/file/img001/XaPLWI52RYK3jYm8x3Byrw.png but when I tried with the repository I cloned from them, it didn't work anyways and I am not looking to clone a new repository with a new theme, I'd like to remove it to the current theme: https://github.com/sabry134/Sparkles-wiki.git.

Answer (score 0):

I think to achieve that kind of customization you need to either switch to their Business version,

https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/commercial/index.html

or self host your documentation somewhere else. Things like Cloudflare Pages or Azure Static Web Apps are quite common.